# Eclipse runs old code even after building the new one

Tags: c++, eclipse

I started to study c++ and i choosen Eclipse IDE for it.
I need some basic instructions.

Even after i compile my code with ctrl+b Eclipse shows me the old "Hello World" program in console. If i look up the compiled .exe files in my projects "Release" folder i can ran my new program very well.

For some reason Eclipse does not refresh output console.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you didn't closed application properly after debug run. So debug distribution could not be created due to File access problem.

Comment: To get more information you can look at the log file of eclipse which is located under.../worspace/.metadata/.log.

Comment: Hah, its just simple main function with return value and some printings to standard output, it should be closed properly.

Comment: Hmm. Then my suggestion was not usefull. But by the way i also  tried to use eclipse cdt some time ago and switch fast back to the visual studio. In my opinion eclipse is for java and everthing what is needed to create Java Enterprise apps. There is the strenght in eclipse in the means of a IDE.

Comment: This happened to me, but I was updating one of 2 functions and calling the wrong one from main. :)  And it was FizzBuzz on top of that!  Just thought I'd share that embarrassing story...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw at the **output console's setting's that it is showing my project's Debug release**.
So i searched for the compiled in my Debug folder and **i saw it was the old .exe of my project**.
After that i did the **same thing within the Release folder that was the new code!**

So all i did was **changed the run configuration to Release,** pic below.

[image]

And now it is working.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried checking that there are not still multiple consoles open. On the console tab try clicking the Display Selected Console button, or pushing the red terminate button until it becomes greyed out and then running it again.

Comment: My problem was similiar, thanks for this suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

**Just clean the project from menu...**